# Apply subsurf modifier to only part of an object

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I apply a modifier only to a part of an object? I want to model a goblet with a pedestal, and if I add a subsurf, the pedestal, of course, gets an unwanted round shape. How can I avoid that? I have tried Googling it, but, to my surprise, found nothing.

Comment: The quality of all the aswers is overwhelming, thank you all very much !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is possible on some modifiers via vertex groups, however this is not possible with subsurf modifier.

You could instead try some of these:

For reference, here is the original subsurfed mesh:

[image]

- [Separate](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting#Separating_Objects) the pedestal and goblet into different objects (*<kbd>P</kbd> > By Selection*). E.g. by separating the face of the cube on the `+X` axis:

  [image]
- You can *[Split](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Vertices#Split)* off geometry in *Edit Mode* with <kbd>Y</kbd>. This will give basically the same result as *Separate*, but within a single object:

  [image]
- You could also use the *[Edge Split](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Edge_Split)* modifier the same way, by either using *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > Mark Sharp*, or with the *Edge Angle* property.
- [Use supporting geometry](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf#Edge_Loops) (i.e. edgeloops) to make edges less round. You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to add loopcuts, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to bevel edges (using the mousewheel to adjust the number of segments). E.g. bevel with `2` segments:

  [image]
- Use [*Mean crease*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf#Weighted_Creases) to make edges less round (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>). E.g. with a *Crease* weight of *1*:

  [image]

Comment: Mean Crease worked marvelously for me, thank you very very much ! before i accept your answer i want to give a chance to others to answer the question with the partial application :-) but again thanks for fast answer ... I would give +1 but i dont have 15 rep here yet -___-

Comment: @Gunslinger As far as I can tell, they are the same thing. It is called mean crease in the `Ctrl+E` menu, and Mean Crease (or Crease if only one edge is selected) in the properties region.

Answer (score 12):

Another way would be to separate the mesh into two objects and group them. 
After that you can assign modifiers as you like to the different parts of the mesh,

- First select some vertices in the Edit Mode, <kbd>P</kbd> to Separate,

[image]

- Select both objects and set one as parent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Yet another way, is to use **Bevel** modifier. For comparison, here's the result of *Edge Crease*:

[image: 1a]

... and with *Edge Bevel Weight* + **Bevel** modifier:

[image: 2a]

Both are done by marking the same set of edges, the latter with *Edge Bevel Weight*,

[image: 3a]

... then placing a **Bevel** modifier atop (applied before) the **Subsurf**, setting its limit method to *Weight* so it uses each edge's bevel weight to consider which ones to bevel:

[image: 4a]

The bevel's smoothness can be further configured by tweaking the modifier's *Width* and *Segments* settings. In contrast with edge crease, this method adds vertices, even more with each additional **Bevel** segments:

[image: 5a]

Comment: very detailed answer +1

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this problem but have decent solution if you do not mind Triangles

select all the faces you do not want subdivided
add the subdivision modifier set the values and apply it
go to edit mode the selected area should also contain the subdivided poly's
right click
UN-Subdivide