# Hard edges during smoothing

Tags: edges

[image]
[image]

I am trying to model a Lamorghini which has some sharp edges.

The problem is when I create a mesh for the bonnet and use `smooth` in a left window all hard edges are gone (red in first picture).

I am watching lots of tutorials all over the internet but so far I haven't found the answer for my specific question. When I smooth the bonnet in the left menu (smooth faces) all my hard edges are gone and I have no idea how to bring them back.

Additionally there should be a sharp edge where is the clipping edge with the mirror part of the car (in the middle). There is always some stupid shading on it, I tried to get rid of it by pressing `ctrl + m` and it worked a bit but I need sharp edge there also. I simply want to model exactly the shape which is in the reference photo of the red lambo. And I want to have it smooth without seeing the faces.

Your kind advice would be really appreciated. (The rendered picture I provided has the lines and smoothness as I want it but the bonnet is created from 3 different parts separately and when i put them together with `ctrl + j` those nice edges will dissappear again)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14009/how-to-maintain-smooth-curves-on-meshes-with-lots-of-uneven-loopcuts and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5705/apply-subsurf-modifier-to-only-part-of-an-object/5706#5706